# En una parte me marca NaN cuando muestro por consola

Tags: javascript

Es un código que no sé si esté bien y en una parte me marca NaN cuando muestro por consola.

> Hacer dos funciones que reciban como parametro un arreglo con numeros aleatorios (minimo 10 numeros), la primera funcion debe retornar la suma de todos los numeros pares y la segunda debe retornar la resta de todos los numeros impares, finalmente, se debe multiplicar el resultado de ambas funciones

```js
 let num = Array.from({length: 10}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)) 
    num.forEach(function(item, index, arr){
        console.log(item)
    }
    )

    const sumOfNumbers = (num) => {
    const filteringNumbers = num.filter((valor)=> valor > 0) 
    console.log(`El resultado de la funcion es: ${filteringNumbers.reduce((a,b)=>a+b)}`)
    
    }
   sumOfNumbers(num)
   
   const restOfNumbers = (num) => {
    const filteringNumbers1 = num.filter((valor)=> valor > 1) 
    console.log(`El resultado de la funcion es: ${filteringNumbers1.reduce((a,b)=>a-b)}`)
    
    }
   restOfNumbers(num)
   console.log(`El resultado de la multiplicacion de los valores res y suma son: ${sumOfNumbers * restOfNumbers} `)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así funcionaría todo, las funciones deben tener un return para que al llamarlas devuelvan algo, sino solo lo muestra en consola con los connsole.log adentro de cada función, pero al llamarlas desde otro lado no retornan nada, por otro lado deposité el resultado de las funciones en variables, para mostrarlas en el último console.log, y dentro de cada función el console.log y el return devuelven result, dentro de result puse cada filter, por el scope de la función se puede utilizar el mismo nombre en ambas.

```
let num = Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
num.forEach(function (item, index, arr) {
  console.log(item);
});

const sumOfNumbers = (num) => {
  const filteringNumbers = num.filter((valor) => valor > 0);
  let result = filteringNumbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  console.log(`El resultado de la funcion es: ${result}`);
  return result;
};
let sumResult = sumOfNumbers(num);

const restOfNumbers = (num) => {
  const filteringNumbers1 = num.filter((valor) => valor > 1);
  let result = filteringNumbers1.reduce((a, b) => a - b);
  console.log(`El resultado de la funcion es: ${result}`);
  return result;
};
let restResult = restOfNumbers(num);

// Acá si ponés las variables dentro de los backticks te quedan como texto, por lo que no realiza la operación.  
    console.log(
  "El resultado de la multiplicacion de los valores res y suma son: " + sumResult * restResult
);
```

Para saber si un número es par o impar, se utiliza algo llamado módulo, ejemplo:

```
22 % 2 === 0 //devuelve true es par
22 % 2 !== 0 //devuelve false es impar
```

El módulo es el resto de la división, si da 0 es porque el valor es divisible entre 2, sino no, así sabemos si es par o no.

---

```
let num = Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
num.forEach(function (item, index, arr) {
});
console.log(num)

const sumOfNumbers = (num) => {
  const filteringNumbers = num.filter((valor) => valor % 2 === 0);
  let result = filteringNumbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  console.log(`El resultado de la funcion es: ${result}`);
  return result;
};
let sumResult = sumOfNumbers(num);

const restOfNumbers = (num) => {
  const filteringNumbers1 = num.filter((valor) => valor % 2 !== 0);
  let result = filteringNumbers1.reduce((a, b) => a - b);
  console.log(`El resultado de la funcion es: ${result}`);
  return result;
};
let restResult = restOfNumbers(num);

console.log(
  "El resultado de la multiplicacion de los valores res y suma son: " +
    sumResult * restResult
);
```

Ahí estaría completo con los pares e impares, agregué el console.log de num al principio, para ver los números generados en un array, en vez de uno por línea en cada iteración del for.

Comment: buenas noches, amigo muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero el ultimo console .log necesita multiplicar los resultados de la suma y la resta y otra cosa como puedo utilizar los modulos dentro de este codigo?

Comment: Ahí quedó modificado con la multiplicación, recuerda ver lo de los pares, te falta eso, solo debes agregarlo al primer filter en cada función, y recuerda votar y dar por solucionada la respuesta si resolvió tu duda. Debes darle a la flechita arriba y al visto al costado de la respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: Ahí agregué abajo en la respuesta todo resuelto, con los pares, impares y corri el console.log de num al principio, para que se muestre el array como array en una sola línea, y no una linea por cada número que devuelve el for.

Comment: muchas gracias ya entendi un poco mas todo, soy muy lento de aprender, pero esto de la programacion me esta gustando y quiero tener bases muy solidad

Comment: Lleva tiempo, frustración, dolores de cabeza, pero de apoco todo empieza a tomar forma y tener sentido, entonces se vuelve aun más hermoso, es una comunidad hiper colaborativa, nunca estamos solos, quizás algún día te toque ayudarme en una duda, ha sido un placer, éxitos en este camino!